# Unicode character automatically change when reopen Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unicode, visual-studio-2015

I have a weird issue with Visual Studio. I'm using a custom font similar to Font Awesome to show icons inside labels.

If I set the text property of the label using code like this:

```
label1.Text = "\uE001";
```

everything works fine.

The problem occurs when I try to set the character with the visual editor. I'm using this site https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter to copy and paste the char inside the text property of the label (since \uE001 doesn't work in visual mode) and the icons works until I close and reopen Visual Studio.

After the reopening the characters is automatically substituded by another character with the code \u0001 (using the same site as before I got the code by pasting the character Visual Studio gave me).

Every code I use after E001 (E002,E003 etc) is always substituted with this other character. Smaller codes like A001, B001 etc or higher codes like F001 are not substitued and works fine.

I also tried making a new project and use the default font but the problem remains.

Can someone explain to me why is this happening?

Comment: Don't edit designer-generated code!  Sure, the designer doesn't like codepoints like this, they are in the private-use area.  You need to set the label's Text property in your form constructor, after the InitializeComponent() call.

Comment: I'm not editing the generated code. I already use the code that i posted in the constructor after InitializeComponent() like you said but that's not ideal because i can't see the icon in the visual editor, i can only see it when i run the application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve